# Mostrar nuevo campo de BD en vista cakephp

Tags: mysql, mvc, cakephp, model

Bueno el problema es el siguiente, cree un campo en la base de datos

@KacosPro

y conecte una pagina para que hiciera un ibdate en esta.

la cosa es que ahora debo conectarla desde otra pagina que muestra una tabla, la cosa es que no me hace nada y yo creo que es por el model

este es el formato de model que siempre he manejado:

```
<?php   
    App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
        class Need extends AppModel {
        public $validate = array(
            'client' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank'
            ),
            'date' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank'
            ),
            'id' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank'
            ),
            'need' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank'
            ),
            'objective' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank'
            ),
            'process' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank'
            )
        );
    }
```

como pueden ver ahi menciono todos los campos que tiene la base de datos, los cuales son client, date, id, need, objective y process.

Ahora en la pagina sobre la que estoy trabajando tiene el siguiente model:

```
class Doctor extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array('Doctitle');
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Education' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Specialty',
                'joinTable' => 'doctor_education',
                'foreignKey' => 'doctor_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'specialty_id',
                'unique' => true,
            ), 
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
            ),
    'acepto' => array(
      'rule' => 'notBlank'
      ),
        'image' => array(
            'rule' => array(
              'isValidMimeType', 
               array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'),
               false
            ),
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'File is not an image',
        ), 
    );



    /* using the upload plugin */
     public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'image' => array(
              'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}img{DS}uploads{DS}',
                'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                    'thumb' => '150w'
                ),
              // uncoment next if "imagick not found"
              'thumbnailMethod' => 'php', 
            ),             
        )
    );

}
```

Yo agregue `'acepto' => array(
          'rule' => 'notBlank'
          ),`pensando que con eso se me conectaría con el campo que cree en la base de datos, pero no fue así.

Este es el controlador :

```
public function admin_index()
{
    //select the layout for the admin
    $this->layout = 'admin';
    $this->response->disableCache();

    $this->Doctor->recursive = 0;
    $DoctorList = $this->Doctor->find('list', array('order' => 'name ASC'));
    $Doctors = $this->Doctor->find('all', array('order' => 'name ASC'));
    $this->set(compact('DoctorList', 'Doctors'));

}
```

O supongo que ese es el controlador ps el según el siguiente boton ahi es donde accede:

```
<?php
        $active = false;
        if($active_menu == 'Cirujanos') $active = 'active';
        echo $this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-user-md fa-fw"></i> <span>Cirujanos</span>', 
                array('controller' => 'doctors', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true), 
                array('escape' => false, 'class' => $active)
        );
    ?>
```

Bueno y aquí están los campos de la BD
[image: BD]
Yo necesito acceder a `acepto` y bueno la vista se carga así:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Foto</th>
                  <th>Trato</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Resumen</th>
                  <th>Aprobo</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php 
                $count = 1;
                foreach ($Doctors as $doctor) {
                  echo "<tr data-doctor_id='".$doctor['Doctor']['id']."' class='activeRow' >";
                    echo "<td>".$count."</td>";
                    if($doctor['Doctor']['image']){
                      echo "<td>";
                      echo $this->Html->image('uploads/'.$doctor['Doctor']['id']."/thumb_".$doctor['Doctor']['image'], 
                              array('alt' => $doctor['Doctor']['name']));
                      echo "</td>";
                    }else{
                      echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                    echo "<td class='bordered'>".$doctor['Doctitle']['title']."</td>";
                    echo "<td class='bordered'>".$doctor['Doctor']['name']."</td>";
                    echo "<td class='bordered'>".substr($doctor['Doctor']['description'], 0, 60)."</td>";
                    echo "<td class='bordered'>".$doctor['Doctor']['acepto']."</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  $count++;
                }
              ?>  
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

En esa tabla carga todos los campos menos el nuevo que yo agregue `echo "<td class='bordered'>".$doctor['Doctor']['acepto']."</td>";`, el `acepto` y los demás si los carga.

Comment: Debe ser por el caché de los modelos, lograste solucionar el problema?

Comment: Hice lo mismo que te mostre en el otro codigo anterior, un select a la antigua.

Comment: Puedes eliminar los archivos dentro de `app/tmp/cache/models/` para que se carguen los nuevos campos

Comment: Por cierto me suscribí a la tag de cakephp para que me avise cuando haya una nueva pregunta, no es necesario que me menciones en las preguntas :D

Comment: Listo ya solo pondré cakephp y listo, jejejejeje

Answer (score 1):

EL código esta bien solo que cuando se agrega un nuevo campo en la base de datos debes de eliminar la memoria cache del modelo para que así este pueda tomar el cambio , luego agregas los inputs en tu vista add y edit con el nombre que guardaste el campo. también es buena práctica eliminar la cache del navegador.

Puedes ir a las ruta `app/tmp/cache/models` y `app/tmp/cache/views` y eliminar todos sus datos o por consola con los siguientes comandos

```
rm -f app/tmp/cache/models/*

rm -f app/tmp/cache/views/*
```